# LTspice simulation for an inductor doesn't output the correct current value

Tags: ltspice, inductor, simulation

I have a very simple circuit in LTspice for an inductor.  The power is an AC voltage source with 50Hz and peak voltage is 640V.  The inductor is 0.1H.  According to the inductive impedance equation X = 2fL, the impedance is 31.415Ω and the maximum current is therefore 20.371A.

According to my simulation result, the maximum current is 18.3738A. Although in LTspice, the inductor has 1mΩ series resistance, it doesn't have significant influence on the final current. What's wrong with my experiment?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the waveform gets less accurate as the total time increases, due to the limited number of steps (you can see it by zooming into the current waveform).

To fix this you can either reduce the simulation time or reduce the 'Maximum Timestep'.

With Timestep set to 1 μs I get 20.3718 A.

Comment: thanks, this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way, ensuring the transient runs for an integer number of 50 Hz cycles:
[image: inductor current]

```
.OP point found by inspection.

inductor_current: AVG(i(l1))=20.3617 FROM 0 TO 0.1


Date: Sun Apr 30 19:17:23 2023
Total elapsed time: 0.216 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 20048
traniter = 20048
tranpoints = 10025
accept = 10024
rejected = 1
matrix size = 2
fillins = 0
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1: off  [0.0]/0.0/0.0
Matrix Compiler2:       9 opcodes  0.0/[0.0]/0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your solution works great. On the otherhand, I have just changed my original simulation to ".tran 0 0.1" other parts keep unchanged, although outputs correct result. Do you know why ".tran 2" or larger number doesn't work

Comment: @RussellH Yes, the time constant can introduce error. In my method, errors grow larger if the transient runs too long, and AVG trends slowly toward zero. Best to run for exactly one cycle, or very few cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The waveform should start at 90 degrees (cosine) to avoid DC offset, and the simulation should skip the initial operating point solution. I also set the inductor series resistance to 10 mOhm. Here is the result:

[image: Inductor current 640 V 100 mH]